# Mysql ERROR 1264 (22003)

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a bash script that stores values in a mysql database.For one value I get an ERROR 1264 (22003).
The line in the script:
`INSERT INTO $TABLE2 (datetime, actualtemp, tempstate) VALUES ("$datetime", "$actual_temp", "$set_temp_state");`

Value of `$actual_temp = 21.0`
Column 'actualtemp' is of type DECIMAL with value/length 2,1
The error:
`ERROR 1264 (22003) at line 2: Out of range value for column 'actualtemp' at row 1`

I have a similar line: `INSERT INTO $TABLE1 (datetime, temperature) VALUES ("$datetime", "$temp");` where `$temp = 2.2` and the column `temperature` is also DECIMAL with value/length 2,1. This line works correctly.

Full script:
`mysql $DB_NAME << EOF
INSERT INTO $TABLE1 (datetime, temperature) VALUES ("$datetime", "$temp");
INSERT INTO $TABLE2 (datetime, actualtemp, tempstate) VALUES ("$datetime", "$actual_temp", "$set_temp_state");
EOF`

21.0 should be a correct value for DECIMAL 2,1, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change M and D of your column to accept numbers larger than 9.9.
Change to DECIMAL(3,1) to accept your value, max number will be 99.9.
You should consider (3,1) means you have 3 digits and 1 of them is fractional part. So 2 digits remaining for integer part.

Look at this doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html
And The point is M is the max number of digits.
Anyway I suggest to use float instead of decimal, because decimal needs more space than float. Except when you want exact representation.

Comment: I'm going to try it...
Update: still the same error, for both DECIMAL (9,9) and DECIMAL (3.1)
Changing to FLOAT doesn't change things.

Comment: Your latest addition worked! For decimal I had to change it to 65,9 since 65 is the maximum (I got an error message).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wtrdk You should consider (3,1) means you have 3 digits and 1 of them is fractional part. So 2 digits remaining for integer part. Mind that (65,9) will take 65/2 byte for each value.

Comment: I interpreted 2,1 as 2 digits and 1 decimal. now I understand! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your decimal variable is not defined correctly, with `actualtemp decimal(2,1)` you have space for 1 integer digit and 1 digit for the decimal part. Consider to read `DECIMAL` definition in this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

If you insert into `actualtemp` value 2.123123, it won't fail, although it will be rounded, but if you insert 10.0 it will fail with `ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column`

Consider to modify your column definition with more digits, I put 3, you can change it as much as digits you need:

`ALTER TABLE YOURDATABASE.YOURTABLE MODIFY actualtemp DECIMAL(3,1)`